# Excel text formula to extract words separated by semicolons in a field

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A field in Excel contains words separated by semicolons, e.g.:

> A1 = save;the;national;treasure;for;good

How can I apply Excel text formulas to produce separate words from this field in another fields? E.g.:

```
A2 should contain a formula to get the first word ("save")
A3 should contain a (different) formula to get the second word ("the")
etc.
```

However these formulas should hold good even when the value in A1 changes, e.g. if the value of A1 is changed to

> A1 = hello;there;how;are;you

Any help in this respect will be highly appreciated.

(The problem is writing a function of my own is not allowed in this case, I have to use original functions like `find`, `search`, `mid`, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your text to parse in A1 then the following formulas should work

In A2 enter the formula

```
=IF(ISERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(";",A1)-1)),A1,LEFT(A1,FIND(";",A1)-1))
```

In B2 enter the formula

```
=IF(ISERROR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(";",A1))),"",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(";",A1)))
```

You can then copy those down as far as you need. Column A grabs the left most word, and Column B displays the remaining string to be parsed. If it runs out of words to parse the formula will display a blank. Column B can also be hidden.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a VBA function to split the fields from this [example](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/the_versatile_split_function/):

```
Function ExtractElement(str, n, sepChar)
'   Returns the nth element from a string,
'   using a specified separator character
    Dim x As Variant
    x = Split(str, sepChar)
    If n > 0 And n - 1 <= UBound(x) Then
       ExtractElement = x(n - 1)
    Else
        ExtractElement = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Then the A2 formula would be: `=ExtractElement(A1, 1, ";")` and A3 would be: `=ExtractElement(A1, 2, ";")` and so on

Comment: if i need to support only upto 4 words in A1 

and instead of using a functin we can use many intermediate formulas 
in different fields 

is a solution possible

Answer (score 1):

If you can use intermediate formulae, then this will work:

A1 -- save;the;national;treasure;for;good

B1 -- blank

C1 -- =IFERROR(FIND(";",$A1,1+(B1)),LEN($A1)+1)

copy C1 into D1:H1

C2 -- =MID($A1,B1+1,(C1-B1)-1)

copy C2 into D2:H2

Row 1 will display the position of each semi-colon in A1, because it starts looking in the string one character past the semi-colon found in the previous cell.

eg cell E1 searches for a semi-colon in A1 starting at D1+1 =10.

The iferror statement in C1:H1 traps the error which will occur when the search finds no further semi-colons, and returns the full length of string A1, plus 1 for an imaginary semi-colon at the end.

B1 needs to be blank to create an initial zero.

Cells C2:H2 then use the Mid function to copy the section of the A1 string starting one character after the value in each of B1:G1, with length (C1-B1)-1, (d1-c1)-1 etc (minus one to cut out the semi-colon itself)

You should get: 5, 9,18,27,31,36 in Row 1, and beneath those cells the individual words.

Hope this helps.